# Права по типу почтового ящика

Tags: права, unix, linux

Имеется папка на сервере, на которую нужно расставить права по типу почтового ящика:

- любой может положить письмо в почтовый ящик,
- только некоторые могут извлечь письмо из почтового ящика.

Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на ваш вопрос вы найдете [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) + надо разделить пользователей системы на две группы, одной группе только запись, другой - все остальное (соответственно пользователи и администратор).